# In cookbook, How I can pass parameters need during the installation?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I start with chef, and I wan't create a cookbook for install my application. But I don't find, how I can pass parameters during my install.

My application need install path, and path for a other application during installation.

edit : 
My environment for my test is a virtual machine vagrant on ubuntu 10.04
and my application is now save in a local directory on my workstation. It's a .run executable.

Sorry, I went too fast in my request, without asking the question of how do I install it.

How can I install an application .Run to be located in my cookbook in the files folder.
Afterwards I would like to know how I can personalized the settings during my runtime. And run my application with argument "-h" for default options

Comment: How are you packaging your application? Is it an RPM, Gem, tarball etc? How are you distributing the application? i.e. Is it hosted on a yum server, a gem server or are you bundling it into the cookbook? Can you give more detail on the chef code that you have used in your attempt to install the application?

Comment: you mean to say u want to pass parameters at run time ..??